# One or more layout are missing the layout height and layout width error when Loading these property from style

Tags: android

I am writing an app in android studio that all property of `TextViews` are same except `id` and `text`. For this reason I declare a style in `style.xml` as below:

```
<style name="thirdTextView" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_vertical</item>
    </style>
```

In my `activity_main.xml` I used this style:

```
<TextView
                style="@style/thirdTextView"
                android:text="@string/questionWeight"/>
```

But I can not see the preview of layout and I got this error:

```
One or more layouts are missing the layout_width and layout_height attributes
```

How to solve this?

Comment: you have to declare `layout_width` and `layout_height` in  XML file.

Comment: @Anmol I declare them in xml file but I still got that error and I can see the preview. I invalidate and reset the cache also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your TextViews to this;

```
<TextView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   style="@style/thirdTextView"
   android:text="@string/questionWeight"/>
```

Every widget in a layout file needs height and width attributes. Hope, this helps.

Comment: Then what's the use of style?

Comment: This is how its explained here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/style-resource. I also never made it work if I define height and width in styles.

Comment: style can be  used to declare the appearance of the View, but layout setup need to be declared in the View xml

Comment: So there is no way to declare global height and width attribute for views?

Comment: Keep them in your style, but also define in layout XML (consider it a placeholder, just assign them wrap_contents). As I know, your style will override the layout entries. Sorry, I can't try this right now as not having access to my laptop.

Comment: @Joe I have added these two attributes to textview in activity_main.xml file but still I got that error.

Comment: Can you share your layout file activity_main.xml?

Comment: @Joe I delete my .AndroidStudio3.2 folder on Users directory and also add layout_width and layout_height to each view. My app is running now. Thanks